# Linear maps that increase majorization order

Tags: order-theory, majorization

Let $x$ a vector in $d$ dimensions with positive entries summing to one (a probability distribution). Is there a characterization of the linear operators $T:R^{d}_{+}\to R^{d}_{+}$ such that:
$$
x\prec Tx
$$
for all probability distributions $x$, with $\prec$ the majorization order?  Thanks Fabio

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "majorization order"?

Comment: Is an order on vectors, see e.g.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization